# Does .NET/Link work with .NET 7.0 assemblies?

Tags: .netlink

Is it possible to call methods in a .NET 7.0 assembly from Mathematica? If so, then how is that accomplished?

This is my first foray using .NET/Link. I was able to get a test project working that calls .NET Framework 4.7.2 assemblies. But calling an identically-coded library built as a .NET 7.0 assembly fails reporting `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0 ...`, etc.

So, .NET/Link is not discovering the (non-GAC'd) .NET Core system assemblies.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?